# How to reset a maze

Tags: python, pygame, maze

I'm trying to do a maze in pygame but I have a problem when I open my first maze everything is fine but when I close it and open another one my maze the 2 mazes are on each other. I tried to restart my tkinter page and do a pygame.quit but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import random
import pygame
from random import randint
from tkinter import*
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load('vaisseau.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() #creation du rectangle Player
                                                #Rect(left, top, width, height)
                                                #left: le point ou le rectangle commence pareil pour le top
        self.rect.x=23
        self.rect.y=27
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        # Bouge chaque axes separement 
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)
    
    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        
        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
 
        # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
             if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):#test si deux rectangles se chevauchent
                if dx > 0: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
 
 
class Wall():
 
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 25, 25)
        

class labyrinthe_aleatoire():
    def __init__(self):
        self.niveau = randint(1,3)
  
    def implementation(self):
        x=1
        y=1
        if self.niveau==1:

            for row in level1:#pour chaque ligne dans le niveau
                for col in row:#pour chaque colonne dans la ligne
                    if col == "W": # si une colonne est la lettre W
                        Wall((x,y)) #alors on cree un mur  au coordonne x et y
                    x += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'abcisse
                    
                y += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'ordonne 
                x = 1 #on revient au point 0 des abcisses

        elif self.niveau==2:
            
            
            for row in level2:#pour chaque ligne dans le niveau
                for col in row:#pour chaque colonne dans la ligne
                    if col == "W": # si une colonne est la lettre W
                        Wall((x,y)) #alors on cree un mur  au coordonne x et y
                    
                    x += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'abcisse
                y += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'ordonne 
                x = 1 #on revient au point 0 des abcisses

        elif self.niveau==3:
            
            for row in level3:#pour chaque ligne dans le niveau
                for col in row:#pour chaque colonne dans la ligne
                    if col == "W": # si une colonne est la lettre W
                        Wall((x,y)) #alors on cree un mur  au coordonne x et y

                    x += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'abcisse
                y += 25 #on ajoute 25 a l'ordonne 
                x = 1 #on revient au point 0 des abcisses

def f1():
    global fenetre1
    fenetre1=Tk()
    fenetre1.geometry("750x600")
    fenetre1.title("Snake") #titre de la fenêtre
    Titre1 = Label(fenetre1, text="MAZE",font=('Fixedsys',55),foreground='white')
    Titre1.pack(side= TOP)

    texte3 = Label(fenetre1, text="by Alexandre,Aaron,Maxime,Roméo",font=('Fixedsys',13),foreground = 'red',)
    texte3.pack(expand = YES )
    
    lan = Button(fenetre1, text ='Niveau Aléatoire',font=("Fixedsys",20),width=17,height=1,command = maze)
    lan.pack(expand = YES )
    
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "level1.png")
    level1bt= Button(fenetre1, text ='Level 1 ',font=("Fixedsys",20),width=700,height=86,command = niveau1,image = photo)
    level1bt.pack(expand = YES)
    
    photo2 = PhotoImage(file = "levelmario.png")
    level2bt= Button(fenetre1, text ='Level 2 ',font=("Fixedsys",12),width=700,height=86 ,command = niveau2,image = photo2)
    level2bt.pack(expand = YES)
    
    photo3 = PhotoImage(file = "levelamongus.png")
    level3bt= Button(fenetre1, text ='Level 3 ',font=("Fixedsys",12),width=700,height=87,command = niveau3,image= photo3)
    level3bt.pack(expand = YES)
    
    photo4 = PhotoImage(file = "leveltetris.png")
    level4bt= Button(fenetre1, text ='Level 4 ',font=("Fixedsys",12),width=700,height=87,command = maze,image= photo4)
    level4bt.place(x = 520 , y = 220)
    level4bt.pack(expand = YES)
    
    fenetre1.mainloop()




def MainLevel(x,y,dimension,bg):
    running = True
    end_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y , 25, 25)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dimension)
    back = pygame.image.load(bg)

    while running:
        
        clock.tick(60)
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        
            
       
 
       # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:#si la fleche gauche est presse le joueur se deplace de -2 sur les abcisses
            player.move(-3, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:#si la fleche droite est presse le joueur se deplace de 2 sur les abcisses
            player.move(3, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:#si la fleche du haut est presse le joueur se deplace de -2 sur les ordonne(vers le haut)
            player.move(0, -3)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:#si la fleche du bas est presse le joueur se deplace de 2 sur les ordonne(vers le bas)
            player.move(0, 3)
 
        # Just added this to make it slightly fun ;)

        if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):#test si deux rectangles se chevauchent      
            restart()

        # Draw the scene
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
        screen.blit(player.image,player.rect)
        
        pygame.display.flip()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    restart()

    
def restart():
    fenetre1.destroy()
    pygame.quit()
    f1()
    
def niveau1():

    labyrinthe.niveau = 1
    labyrinthe.implementation()
    MainLevel(720,470,(850, 600),"back.png")
    


def niveau2():

    labyrinthe.niveau = 2
    labyrinthe.implementation()
    MainLevel(1550,575,(1600, 760),"mario_level.png")

def niveau3():

    labyrinthe.niveau =3
    labyrinthe.implementation()
    MainLevel(1550,575,(1760, 800),"mario_level.png")


def  maze():
    running = True
    labyrinthe.implementation()
    x=y=w=h=0
    screen = 0
    bg =0
    if labyrinthe.niveau == 1:
         x=720
         y=470
         w=850
         h=600
         bg="back.png"
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h ))
    elif labyrinthe.niveau == 2:
        x=1550
        y=575
        w=1600
        h=760
        bg="mario_level.png"
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
        
    
    MainLevel(x,y,(w,h),bg)





    

  
 

pygame.init()#
 
pygame.display.set_caption("Va au carre rouge!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = []
player = Player()
labyrinthe = labyrinthe_aleatoire()

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
level1= [
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
  "                          W   W",
  "W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
  "W  W  W  W        W        W  W",
  "W  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W",
  "W  W     W  W        W        W",
  "W  W  W  W  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W",
  "W     W  W  W  W     W        W",
  "W  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW",
  "W     W           W  W        W",
  "W  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW",
  "W           W                 W",
  "WWWW  WWWW  W  W  W  WWWWWWW  W",
  "W     W     W  W  W     W     W",
  "WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
  "W        W  W           W     W",
  "W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW",
  "W        W  W  W     W  W  W  W",
  "W  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  W" ,                              
  "W  W        W                 W" , 
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"

]
level2 = [
    

"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W      W  W        W  W                    W     W  W          W",
"WWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWWWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  W",
"W     W  W        W  W     W  W  W  W              W     W  W  W",
"WWWW  W  W  W  W  W  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW",
"W           W  W           W     W           W  W              W",
"W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
"W  W     W  W     W  W     W        W  W     W  W              W",
"W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  W",
"W     W     W  W  W  W           W  W     W  W        W     W  W",
"W  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W",
"W  W  W           W  W  W  W                    W  W  W  W     W",
"WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  W",
"W           W     W  W  W     W        W           W     W  W  W",
"W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  W",
"W  W     W           W  W        W  W  W     W     W     W  W  W",
"W  W  W  W  W  WWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  W  W",
"W  W  W  W  W     W  W        W     W        W  W  W  W  W     W",
"W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  W",
"W  W  W           W  W  W  W        W  W     W        W     W  W",
"W  W  WWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWWWWW",
"W     W  W  W  W     W        W  W     W     W        W     W  W",
"W  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWW  W",
"W     W     W           W           W  W  W        W          W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",


]

level3 = [


"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W         W  W  W     W           W  W                 W             W",
"WWWWWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  W  W  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWW",
"W  W     W  W        W  W  W  W     W  W           W        W     W  W",
"W  W  W  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  W",
"W     W     W     W              W  W        W  W     W              W",
"WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  W",
"W  W  W              W  W  W  W     W           W  W  W  W  W  W  W  W",
"W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  W  W",
"W        W        W           W           W     W           W  W     W",
"W  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  W",
"W     W              W     W     W     W  W     W     W  W           W",
"W  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWW",
"W     W     W  W           W        W  W     W  W     W     W        W",
"W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWWWWW  W  WWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWW  W  W  W",
"W        W     W  W  W  W           W     W        W        W  W  W  W",
"W  W  WWWW  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  W  WWWW  W",
"W  W     W  W  W  W        W  W  W        W  W     W  W  W     W     W",
"W  W  WWWWWWW  W  WWWWWWWWWW  W  W  W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  W  WWWW  WWWW",
"W  W  W  W  W              W     W  W  W     W     W  W  W  W  W  W  W",
"W  W  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  W  WWWWWWW  WWWW  WWWW  W  W  W  W  W  W  W",
"W  W        W     W  W     W  W  W     W                 W     W     W",
"WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  W  W  WWWW  W  W  W  W  WWWW  WWWW  W",
"W     W  W     W     W              W        W  W  W  W  W  W     W  W",
"WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  W  W  W  WWWW",
"W        W  W     W     W              W  W  W        W  W  W  W     W",
"W  WWWW  W  W  W  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W  WWWW  WWWWWWW  W  W  WWWWWWW  W",
"W  W     W  W  W        W  W  W  W  W  W     W     W  W        W     W",
"W  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W  W  W  W  WWWW  WWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  WWWWWWW  W",
"W     W        W     W        W                          W     W     W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",


]





f1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reset all your global variables and classes about your maze :
You can do that by using a restart function that closes the previous window and that resets the variables.

Here is an example :

```
def restart():
    global walls,player,labyrinthe,clock
    pygame.quit()
    pygame.init()
 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Va au carre rouge!")

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    walls = []
    player = Player()
    labyrinthe = labyrinthe_aleatoire()
```

You don't need to restart the tk process f1 as it is running in background

Comment: Thanks for your answers you helped me a lot!!